# cant install z3 on windows 10

Tags: python, z3

I have installed many packages and never had a problem
possible reasons??

wheel problem
trying to compile something
the file it seems to want in Wondershare is not there

```
C:\Users\XXXX
λ pip install z3-solver
Collecting z3-solver
  Using cached z3-solver-4.5.1.0.post2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: z3-solver
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for z3-solver ... error
  Complete output from command "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-build-uehmymoh\\z3-solver\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmp9uv6yw5apip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Configuring Z3
  opt = -x, arg =
  New component: 'util'
  New component: 'lp'
  New component: 'polynomial'
  New component: 'sat'
  New component: 'nlsat'
  New component: 'hilbert'
  New component: 'simplex'
  New component: 'automata'
  New component: 'interval'
  New component: 'realclosure'
  New component: 'subpaving'
  New component: 'ast'
  New component: 'rewriter'
  New component: 'normal_forms'
  New component: 'model'
  New component: 'tactic'
  New component: 'substitution'
  New component: 'parser_util'
  New component: 'grobner'
  New component: 'euclid'
  New component: 'core_tactics'
  New component: 'sat_tactic'
  New component: 'arith_tactics'
  New component: 'nlsat_tactic'
  New component: 'subpaving_tactic'
  New component: 'aig_tactic'
  New component: 'solver'
  New component: 'ackermannization'
  New component: 'interp'
  New component: 'cmd_context'
  New component: 'extra_cmds'
  New component: 'smt2parser'
  New component: 'proof_checker'
  New component: 'simplifier'
  New component: 'fpa'
  New component: 'macros'
  New component: 'pattern'
  New component: 'bit_blaster'
  New component: 'smt_params'
  New component: 'proto_model'
  New component: 'smt'
  New component: 'bv_tactics'
  New component: 'fuzzing'
  New component: 'smt_tactic'
  New component: 'sls_tactic'
  New component: 'qe'
  New component: 'duality'
  New component: 'muz'
  New component: 'dataflow'
  New component: 'transforms'
  New component: 'rel'
  New component: 'pdr'
  New component: 'clp'
  New component: 'tab'
  New component: 'bmc'
  New component: 'ddnf'
  New component: 'duality_intf'
  New component: 'fp'
  New component: 'nlsat_smt_tactic'
  New component: 'ufbv_tactic'
  New component: 'sat_solver'
  New component: 'smtlogic_tactics'
  New component: 'fpa_tactics'
  New component: 'portfolio'
  New component: 'smtparser'
  New component: 'opt'
  New component: 'api'
  New component: 'shell'
  New component: 'test'
  New component: 'api_dll'
  New component: 'dotnet'
  New component: 'java'
  New component: 'ml'
  New component: 'cpp'
  Python bindings directory was detected.
  New component: 'python'
  New component: 'python_install'
  New component: 'cpp_example'
  New component: 'z3_tptp'
  New component: 'c_example'
  New component: 'maxsat'
  New component: 'dotnet_example'
  New component: 'java_example'
  New component: 'ml_example'
  New component: 'py_example'
  Generating src\util\version.h from src\util\version.h.in
  Generated 'src\util\version.h'
  Generating src\api\dotnet\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs from src\api\dotnet\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs.in
  Generated 'src\api\dll\api_dll.def'
  Generated 'src\ackermannization\ackermannization_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ackermannization\ackermannize_bv_tactic_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\pp_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\fpa\fpa2bv_rewriter_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\normal_forms\nnf_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\pattern\pattern_inference_params_helper.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\rewriter\arith_rewriter_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\rewriter\array_rewriter_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\rewriter\bool_rewriter_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\rewriter\bv_rewriter_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\rewriter\fpa_rewriter_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\rewriter\poly_rewriter_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\rewriter\rewriter_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\simplifier\arith_simplifier_params_helper.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\simplifier\array_simplifier_params_helper.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\simplifier\bv_simplifier_params_helper.hpp'
  Generated 'src\interp\interp_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\math\polynomial\algebraic_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\math\realclosure\rcf_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\model\model_evaluator_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\model\model_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\muz\base\fixedpoint_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\nlsat\nlsat_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\opt\opt_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\parsers\util\parser_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\sat\sat_asymm_branch_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\sat\sat_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\sat\sat_scc_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\sat\sat_simplifier_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\smt\params\smt_params_helper.hpp'
  Generated 'src\solver\combined_solver_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\tactic\sls\sls_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\tactic\smtlogics\qfufbv_tactic_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\util\lp\lp_params.hpp'
  Generated 'src\ast\pattern\database.h'
  Generated 'src\shell\install_tactic.cpp'
  Generated 'src\test\install_tactic.cpp'
  Generated 'src\api\dll\install_tactic.cpp'
  Generated 'src\shell\mem_initializer.cpp'
  Generated 'src\test\mem_initializer.cpp'
  Generated 'src\api\dll\mem_initializer.cpp'
  Generated 'src\shell\gparams_register_modules.cpp'
  Generated 'src\test\gparams_register_modules.cpp'
  Generated 'src\api\dll\gparams_register_modules.cpp'
  Generated 'src\api\python\z3\z3consts.py
  Generated 'src\api\api_log_macros.h'
  Generated 'src\api\api_log_macros.cpp'
  Generated 'src\api\api_commands.cpp'
  Generated 'src\api\python\z3\z3core.py'
  Listing 'src\\api\\python\\z3'...
  Compiling 'src\\api\\python\\z3\\z3consts.py'...
  Compiling 'src\\api\\python\\z3\\z3core.py'...
  Generated python bytecode
  Copied 'z3consts.py'
  Copied 'z3core.py'
  Copied 'z3consts.cpython-36.pyc'
  Copied 'z3core.cpython-36.pyc'
  Testing OpenMP...
  64-bit:         True
  OpenMP:         False
  Writing build\Makefile
  Copied Z3Py example 'all_interval_series.py' to 'build\python'
  Copied Z3Py example 'example.py' to 'build\python'
  Copied Z3Py example 'socrates.py' to 'build\python'
  Copied Z3Py example 'visitor.py' to 'build\python'
  Makefile was successfully generated.
    compilation mode: Release
    platform: x64

  To build Z3, open a [Visual Studio x64 Command Prompt], then
  type 'cd C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-build-uehmymoh\z3-solver\core\build && nmake'

  Remark: to open a Visual Studio Command Prompt, go to: "Start > All Programs > Visual Studio > Visual Studio Tools"
  Building Z3
  error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for z3-solver
  Running setup.py clean for z3-solver
Failed to build z3-solver
Installing collected packages: z3-solver
  Running setup.py install for z3-solver ... error
    Complete output from command "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-build-uehmymoh\\z3-solver\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-cpcgkren-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    Configuring Z3
    Building Z3
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-build-uehmymoh\\z3-solver\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-cpcgkren-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-build-uehmymoh\z3-solver\

C:\Users\XXXX
λ
```

Comment: This might explain why you are having issues: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/63 I just googled your error + z3-solver

Comment: 1 that was 2015

Comment: 2 then why is it ON pypi

Comment: it seems to be c++ source and you are supposed to compile it    this should not be on pypi  I would think    only on Git where anything can be put there is no comment to this affect on pypi  should I complain to them? I am no expert in this and the few times i attempted it was painful  Learning Z3 is work enough!

Comment: 1) Bugs in open source that don't affect lots of people tend to linger 2) your guess is as good as mine. Try compiling from source yourself instead of using pip and see if you have the same issue. That should isolate if it's an issue with your environment.

Comment: but I was trying to do this following their instructions and this happened so where did I go wrong?

Comment: This look like a problem in the package itself. It installs fine via Python 2 but it throws this sort of error when via Python 3. The Z3 team does not maintain that package though and I think this is the package for angr, which contains project-specific modifications. Please create a new issue on their fork: https://github.com/angr/angr-z3 It looks like someone opened a very similar sounding issue already: https://github.com/angr/angr-z3/issues/7

Comment: Thanks so much Chris   I will wait for them to clean up their act Things like  this never cease to amaze me